# Git pull remote repo

Tags: python, git, github

I need to automatically pull down a compressed version of my repo with a python script. What would be the best way to do this?

As far as I know the archive command in git does not support remote repos

Comment: What kind of transport do you use to talk to the server?  Do you have a local working copy of the repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [man git archive](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-archive):

> --remote=<repo>
>
> Instead of making a tar archive from the local repository,
>   retrieve a tar archive from a remote repository.

Comment: How do I specify a repo on github? could you give me an example of a command with a github repo

Comment: GitHub specifically doesn't allow this op. They recommend using their own download links. See: http://groups.google.com/group/github/browse_thread/thread/cfcbcb1dc5f41f16?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

Examples

Create a tar archive that contains the contents of the latest commit on the current branch, and extract it in the /var/tmp/junk directory :

```
git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (cd /var/tmp/ && tar xf -)
```

... on github :

```
wget https://github.com/lgs/grokphoto/tarball/master
```